# Why is this giving me this arrayoutofbounds error?

Tags: java, arrays, debugging

I have these this while loop and for statement. It's doing exactly what I want it to, printing specific parts of an array. However, I keep getting an out of bounds statement. I can't figure it out. I feel like my if statement should prevent the index get larger then it already is.

Note: I already have a method outside of this creating this array and initializing its values, so pretend that the array is two dimensions.

Any suggestions how I can keep it from getting out of bounds?

The purpose is, I want the column and rows to both increment by one until they cannot increment any longer.

```
    int columnincrement = 0;
    String spacing = "\t";
    int diagcol=0;
    int diagrow=0;
    while(diagcol<themainarray[columnincrement].length)
    {

            System.out.println(spacing+themainarray[diagcol][diagrow]);
            spacing+= "\t";
            System.out.print("\n");

            if (diagcol<=themainarray[columnincrement].length)
            {   

            columnincrement++;
            diagcol++;
            diagrow++;

            }


    }
```

Comment: Consider actually debugging the problem.

Comment: (And what is the entire exception message???  Odds are the exception message tells you exactly what's wrong.)

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at TwoDimensionalArray.mainDiagonal(TwoDimensionalArray.java:162)
 at TwoDimensionalArray.main(TwoDimensionalArray.java:38))`

Comment: How big is `themainarray`?

Comment: Do note that your two `while` statements are testing the SAME dimension of the array, so when you get to the end you're almost guaranteed to take an exception in the first `while`.

Comment: Hot licks, the array is based on user input, but is 2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arrays are 0-based.

`arr[arr.length]` will also throw an exception

change your if statement to the following, *note the `<` and thhe `-1`;

```
if (diagcol<themainarray[columnincrement].length - 1)
```

If you make that change, at least there's a chance that your code will run without an indexoutofbounds exception.  it's not a 100% chance.

---

If `themainarray.length` is less than `themainarray[columnincriment].length` than you'll also get an exception, because nowhere are you checking against `themainarray.length`

Comment: and there are a number of other things about your code that aren't best practices, but I don't want to clutter the post too much

Comment: Is it because of the while loops? I had them originally as for loops but I got the exceptions. I figured I'd try something else.

Comment: @munchschair it's more about the fact that you're using `digacol` to check the lengths of arrays indexed by other values

Comment: it's not an error per-se, it.s just sloppy coding.  If you're going to use the values interchangeably like that, you might as well just use 1 value.

Comment: I don't know what a digacol is. I'm pretty n00b, so I'm open to any piece of advice really.

Comment: (Oh I see, you're referring to the variable). That's true, I could just use one variable.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I figured out something to check for the length both ways before it increments, or else it sends the number too high for the while loop to ring true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were checking the wrong things. It looks like in the while look you wanted the amount of items in the first part of the d2array and the if statement you wanted the amount of items in the second part of the 2darray. This might work:

```
int columnincrement = 0;

String spacing = "\t";
int diagcol=0;
int diagrow=0;
while(diagcol<themainarray.length) {
        System.out.println(spacing+themainarray[diagcol][diagrow]);
        spacing+= "\t";
        System.out.print("\n");

        if (diagrow<=themainarray[columnincrement].length) {   
            columnincrement++;
            diagcol++;
            diagrow++;
        }

}
```